# Initialization of properties in a class, lazy properties in specific?

Tags: swift, properties, initialization, lazy-loading

1. In swift, are properties in a class initialized when I declare an instance of that class?
2. Lazy properties aren't initialized until they are called/used (correct me if I'm wrong) , so basically declaring an instance of a class will not initialize lazy properties but WILL initialize regular properties if there are any (called stored, I believe) ?
3. lastly, the book says that the  instance below is "declared" AND "initialized".......I can see that it IS declared but how is it being "initialized"?? There is not argument being sent in-between the parentheses??

   ```
   let someClass = SomeClassWithLazyVar()
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yep, that is correct.
2. Yep, that is also correct.
3. What is being initialized is the constant `someClass`. *Declaration* is the introduction of a new named value into your program. You declare the name of the constant (or variable) and identify its type like this:

   `let someClass: SomeClassWithLazyVar`

But at that point it still hasn't been *initialized*. You initialize the constant by assigning it a value:

```
someClass = SomeClassWithLazyVar()
```

The vast majority of the time (especially with constants) you declare the constant and initialize it at the same time:

```
let someClass = SomeClassWithLazyVar()
```

Whether or not you need to pass arguments inside the parentheses depends on the initializer for the object that you are creating. I'm assuming that `SomeClassWithLazyVar` has an initializer that takes no arguments, like this:

```
init() { }
```

Comment: Dude you're awesome, thanks a lot ,cleared up a lot of the confusion!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes (only "regular" stored properties - this doesn't apply to computed properties and lazy properties). Even default values are assigned only when an actual instance of the class is created.
2. Yes. Apple Documentations says:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

3. What you pasted is a "constructor call". When you write `name_of_class()` you're actually creating an instance of the class (and calling its `init()` method immediately after). Therefore `someClass` is being initialised with said instance.

Comment: oh ok , and are "constructor calls" the same as an "initializer call", if so, which term is better to use when speaking of topics like this?

Comment: Basically yes, they are. Both expressions are okay to use, I suppose. "constructor call" is more C++-sounding, but you'd be understood either way.